# Laravel DB Select first: The Response content must be a string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I use Laravel and i use DB object if i select with the following statment i get the error: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

`return DB::table('todos')->where("title","your List")->first();`

If i select with the following statment it works:

`return DB::table('todos')->where("title","your List")->get();`

do you know what's wrong with the first statment?

Comment: The first one returns an object and the second one a collection. What happens if you do a dd(DB::table('todos')->where("title","your List")->first())?

Comment: I Get this as result:
{#156 ▼
  +"id": 5
  +"created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  +"updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  +"title": "your List"
  +"isDone": 0
  +"user_id": 1
}

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and I'm getting the same. Gotta look into it a bit more. Do the following:

```
return DB::table('todos')->where("title","your List")->take(1)->get()
```

And you'll be good for now.